# How can do report with dynamic columns

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have table with dynamic columns, Red columns are fixed, and green columns are dynamic[image]

How can do it with iReport, jasperReport???
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **crosstab** with row group by "Grupo de valoracion" field and column group by date field and set function = Sum (if you need sum?) for measure of crosstab.